# Springboot testing w/Security

Tags: spring-boot, testing

I am following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/), with the controller first below and the test second below.  With security enabled it is showing the the default login page and failing the test.  Is there a simple way to bypass security only in testing?  (If I just run the app from a browser, get the test url it works as expected.)

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Data
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public @ResponseBody String greeting(){
        return("Hello, World");
    }
}

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class HttpRequestTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void greetingShouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/home",
                String.class)).contains("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I got it working.  [This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-integration-tests) also was used.  HTH.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class HttpRequestTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

     @WithMockUser("CP")
    @Test    public void greetingShouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/home",
                String.class)).contains("Hello, World");
    }
}
```